# how to create child parent component in AEM?

Tags: aem

how to create child parent component in AEM?

child parent linking where one single component where used by other places by different different component example data-sly-reference?

we can also use resourecType in out component

Answer (score 0):

In the html file of your component add:

```
<div data-sly-resource="${'<unique-name>' @ resourceType = '<project>/components/content/<component>'}"></div>
```

Example:

```
<div data-sly-resource="${'textComponent1' @ resourceType = 'shoeCompany/components/content/text'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Main Component HTML:

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${@path='personalinfo',resourceType = '/components/abc'}"></sly>
```

IMPL Java model:

```
import com.xyz.core.model.abc;
public static final String RESOURCE_TYPE = "xyz/abc";
@ChildResource
private Abcpersonal personal;
public Abcpersonal getPersonalinfo() {return personal;}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?